# D3js zoom/drag not working any more in my code (+code sample)

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

**Code**
In this file http://tc51.net/w/at/stackoverflow.com/20150604.1/20150604.1.zip

You will find all .htm, .js, .css, .csv files of:

- The example I started with
- My current work in progess.

**The problem**
Since I did some refactoring required for further developments, the chart drag/zoom feature is not working anymore. No apparent JavaScript error in debugger, and it seems to have to do with 3Djs inner zoom functions so I have no clue what I did wrong. Can you help me find out? Thank you.

(I tried to create two JSFiddles as well but they don't work at all, I have no idea why: Start example:
https://jsfiddle.net/TTTT/erndok36/2 Current work in progress: https://jsfiddle.net/TTTT/mfudwy0q
)

And here is some code:

```
//Start example: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/area-gradient.html

function parseDate(unix_timestamp){return new Date(unix_timestamp*1000);}
var svg, m, w, h, x, y, xAxis, yAxis, area, line, gradient, margin, varData,
//parseDate = d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d').parse,
format = d3.time.format('%Y')

function CreateSvg()
{
    margin = {top: 79, right: 80, bottom: 160, left: 79};
    //m = [79, 80, 160, 79];
    w = 1280 - margin.right - margin.left;
    h = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    //Scales. Note the inverted domain for the y-scale: bigger is up!
    x = d3.time.scale().range([0, w]);
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([h, 0]);
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom').tickPadding(6).tickFormat(d3.time.format('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')).ticks(30); //.tickSize(-h, 0)
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient('left').tickSize(w).tickPadding(6);

    area = d3.svg.area()
        .interpolate('step-after')
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y0(y(0))
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

    line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate('step-after')
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

    svg = d3.select('#ChartContainer').append('svg:svg')
        .attr('width', w + margin.right + margin.left)
        .attr('height', h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append('svg:g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    gradient = svg.append('svg:defs').append('svg:linearGradient')
        .attr('id', 'gradient')
        .attr('x2', '0%')
        .attr('y2', '100%');

    gradient.append('svg:stop')
        .attr('offset', '40%')
        .attr('stop-color', '#f00')
        .attr('stop-opacity', .5);

    gradient.append('svg:stop')
        .attr('offset', '100%')
        .attr('stop-color', '#0f0')
        .attr('stop-opacity', 1);

    svg.append('svg:clipPath')
        .attr('id', 'clip')
        .append('svg:rect')
        .attr('x', x(0))
        .attr('y', y(1))
        .attr('width', x(1) - x(0))
        .attr('height', y(0) - y(1));

    svg.append('svg:g')
        .attr('class', 'y axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + w + ',0)');

    svg.append('svg:path')
        .attr('class', 'area')
        .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
        .style('fill', 'url(#gradient)');

    svg.append('svg:g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + h + ')');

    svg.append('svg:path')
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)');

    svg.append('svg:rect')
        .attr('class', 'pane')
        .attr('width', w)
        .attr('height', h)
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on('zoom', zoom));

    svg.append('text')
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
        .attr('y', 0-margin.left)
        .attr('x', 0-(h/2))
        .attr('dy', '1em')
        .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .text('Noise (dB)');

    svg.append('text')
        .attr('y', w/2)
        .attr('x', h)
        .attr('dx', '1em')
        .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .text('Time');
}

function CreateData()
{
        //.csv() function is async!
        d3.csv('data-noise-example.csv', function(data)
        {
            data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.date = parseDate(d.date);
                d.value = +d.value;
            });

            //Adds two random data. ''Getting started experimentation code.'
            //data.reverse();
            data.push({date:parseDate(1433160989), value:Math.random() * 180});
            data.push({date:parseDate(1433160990), value:Math.random() * 180});
            data.push({date:parseDate(1433160991), value:179});
            data.push({date:parseDate(1433160992), value:1});
            //data.reverse();

            varData = data;
            ReDraw(varData);
        });
}

function ReDrawTest()
{
    varData.push({date:parseDate(1433160993), value:Math.random() * 180});
    varData.push({date:parseDate(1433160994), value:Math.random() * 180});
    ReDraw(varData);
}

function FirstDraw()
{
    CreateData();
    //ReDraw(varData);
}

function ReDraw(data)
{
        y.domain([0, 180]);
        x.domain([parseDate(1433160660), parseDate(1433160780)]);

        //Bind the data to our path elements
        svg.select('path.area').data([data]);
        svg.select('path.line').data([data]);

        var t = svg.select('g.x.axis').call(xAxis).selectAll('text')
            .style('text-anchor', 'end')
            .attr('dx', '-.8em')
            .attr('dy', '.15em');
        t.attr('transform', 'translate(-2,0)').attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)');

        svg.select('g.y.axis').call(yAxis);
        svg.select('path.area').attr('d', area);
        svg.select('path.line').attr('d', line); //.on('click', clickPath).on('mouseover', onMouseOverPath);
        //d3.select('#footer span').text('U.S. Commercial Flights, ' + x.domain().map(format).join('-'));
}

/*function clickPath(e){
    console.log('onclickPath', this);
    //console.log('onclickPath', this.attr("d")); 
    var coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
        console.log(coordinates[0],coordinates[1]);
}

function findData(x,y)
{
    var relY = Math.abs(height-y)/height;
    var valY = relY*(chartMaxY-chartMinY);
    return [valY,''];
}

function onMouseOverPath(e){
    var coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
    var x = coordinates[0];
    var y = coordinates[1];
    var coordValue =  'Coord.: x:' + x + ',y:' + y;
    $('#coordValue').text(coordValue);
    //Probably not the cleanest way, but that way gives result ...


    //console.log(svg.select('title'));
    //console.log(coordinates[0] + ',' +coordinates[1]);
    var retrievedData = findData(x,y);
    var noiseValue = 'Noise: '+ retrievedData[0]+','+retrievedData[1];
    $('#noiseValue').text(noiseValue);

    svg.append('svg:title').text(noiseValue + "\r\n" + coordValue);
    svg.select('title').text(noiseValue + "\r\n" + coordValue);
}

function onMouseOutPath(){alert('mouseOutPath');}
function click() {alert('onclick');}
function onMouseOver(){alert('mouseOver');}
function onMouseOut(){alert('mouseOut');}*/

function zoom() {
  d3.event.transform(x); //TODO d3.behavior.zoom should support extents
  ReDraw(varData);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    CreateSvg();
    FirstDraw();
});
```

Comment: will be better if you put it on JSFiddle in my opinion

Comment: I tried JSfiddle and Plnkr ... to much hassle to get the code working there. It works perfectly fine on local browser, doesn't it?

Comment: i havent tried, would prefer running scripts on an online compiler if im honest

Comment: Here are 2 JSFiddles but I have not idea why they don't work on Fiddle. Start example: http://jsfiddle.net/TTTT/erndok36/2/ 
Current work in progress: http://jsfiddle.net/TTTT/mfudwy0q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found:
Moving

```
y.domain([0, 180]);
x.domain([parseDate(1433160660), parseDate(1433160780)]);
```

to

```
function FirstDraw(){...}
```

(I thought I had tested it already ...)

Comment: sorry just got back online, glad you found the solution :))